# Is it possible to abbreviate java functions removing the variable?

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, java-8, functional-interface

In Java 8’s functions, there is a shortcut for, i.e.

```
() -> new ArrayList()
```

which then reads:

```
ArrayList::new
```

When working with streams, I find myself declaring a lot of functions like this:

```
s.map(var -> var.getFoo()).flatMap(var -> var.parallelStream()).map(var -> var.getBar())
```

Is there also an abbreviation if the prefix is `var -> var.`? Something like

```
s.map(::getFoo()).flatMap(::parallelStream()).map(::getBar())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of method reference is defined at [JLS-15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) and written as `Object::method` without discussion - you can't write `::method` since the origin of the method would remain unknown. The variable `var` is an instance of an object, right? Thus:

```
s.map(MyObject::getFoo).flatMap(Collection::parallelStream).map(MyObject::getBar)
```

My personal suggestion is to choose the readable way over the short way. Shortening doesn't imply readability. For some reason I don't like `Object::method` method reference and rather use `var -> var.method()`. This is a matter of discussion and personal preference.

However, the statement above the code snippet is definitive. You have to follow the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, the only thing that is possible: use the class name for the method references:

```
s.map(FooHolder::getFoo).flatMap(Whatever::parallelStream).map(OwnersOfBar::getBar)
```

Obviously, that is rather "more" typing. On the other hand, it is a bit more verbose, telling you well, about the types involved.